¿Como puedo optimizar un procedimiento almacenado que inserta conteos de inventario?
Estoy haciendo un insert masivo de conteos con un archivo excel que me genera los conteos de inventario por bodega, el caso es que se demora demaciado en hacer el conteo en la base de datos, he tratado de hacerlo mas eficiente pero aun se sigue demorando entre 5 a 15 minutos dependiendo la hora.
En el procedimiento hago 2 validaciones, primero que si un UPC(codigo de barras) no existe en el sistema o la tienda correspondiente interrumpa el proceso y de un mensaje al usuario con la lista de los upc no existentes.El segundo valida si el GPC(Clasificacion de los productos) correponde si el inventario es parcial.
ALTER proc [dbo].[Ges_CargaConteosExcel]
                                    (
                                         @Cod_Tienda    uniqueidentifier
                                        ,@Usuario       Varchar(20)
                                        ,@xml           xml
                                        ,@Status        int out
                                    )
As
Begin

Declare @Error          Varchar(500)
Declare @Bodega         Varchar(20)
Declare @Codigo_Tienda  int
Declare @Codigo_Bodega  Varchar(1)
Declare @Pos_UPC        Int
Declare @Pos_Est        Int
Declare @Pos_Bodega     Int
Declare @Pos_Total      Int
Declare @Fila           Varchar(max)

update Ges_TIM_ConteosCab
set Estado = 'B'
where Cod_Conteo = (Select top 1 Cod_Conteo from Ges_TIM_ConteosCab 
where Cod_Tienda = @Cod_Tienda
order by Id_Conteo desc)

delete from Ges_Conteo
delete from Ges_Contadores

Set @xml = @xml.query('/*:Workbook/*:Worksheet/*:Table')
Set @xml  = Replace( Convert( varchar(max) , @xml ) , 'p1:' , '')

-- Ajustar el XML para facilitar la lectura, añadiendo delimitador
SET @xml = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '</Data>', '</Data>') AS XML);

-- Insertar datos desde el XML a la tabla temporal
INSERT INTO Ges_Conteo (EAN, Bodega)
SELECT 
    C.value('(Cell[1]/Data/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS UPC,
    C.value('(Cell[2]/Data/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Bodega
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Table/Row') AS T(C)
WHERE 
    C.value('(Cell[1]/Data/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') != 'UPC';  -- Evitar insertar el header


-- Ver los datos insertados
insert into Ges_Contadores
SELECT EAN, Bodega, COUNT(EAN) FROM Ges_Conteo
group by EAN, Bodega

Create table #UPC (
UPC  varchar(20))

Declare @Cod_ProductoTab as uniqueidentifier, @Cod_EstiloColor as uniqueidentifier, @Numtienda as int

SELECT @Numtienda = Codigo_Numerico
FROM Ges_Tiendas with(nolock)
WHERE Cod_Tienda = @Cod_Tienda
-------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO Ges_Prd_StockProductos
SElect NEWID(), @Cod_Tienda, Pr.Cod_Producto, Pr.Cod_EstiloColor, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, @Numtienda
From Ges_Contadores Ean
inner JOIN Ges_Prd_Productos     pr  with(nolock) ON Pr.Codigo_Barra = Ean.EAN  
Left JOIN Ges_Prd_StockProductos Stc with(nolock) on Stc.Cod_Producto = Pr.Cod_Producto
                                                and Stc.Cod_Tienda = @Cod_Tienda
Where Stc.Id_PrdStock is null

-------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO #UPC
SElect Ean.EAN
From Ges_Contadores Ean
Left JOIN Ges_Prd_Productos  pr  with(nolock) ON Pr.Codigo_Barra = Ean.EAN  
Where Pr.Cod_Producto is null

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #UPC)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #UPC;
    SET @Status = 4;
     -- Limpiar tabla temporal
    DROP TABLE #UPC;
    Return
END


DECLARE @Cod_Inv UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @Id_Inv INT,
        @TipoInv VARCHAR(1);

SELECT TOP 1 @Cod_Inv = Pro.Cod_Inventario, @Id_Inv = Pro.Id_Inventario
FROM Gestion.dbo.Ges_TIM_Inventarios Pro WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Cod_Tienda = @Cod_Tienda AND Estado = 'A'
ORDER BY Id_Inventario DESC;

SELECT @TipoInv = Tipo FROM Ges_InventarioCab with(nolock) WHERE Cod_Inventario = @Cod_Inv;

-- Validar el tipo de inventario
IF @TipoInv = 'P'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TipoGpc UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    CREATE TABLE #TempNoGPC(UPC VARCHAR(20));

    SELECT TOP 1 @TipoGpc = d.Cod_GPC
    FROM Ges_InventarioCab c with(nolock)
    INNER JOIN Ges_InventarioDet d with(nolock) ON d.Id_Inventario = c.Id_Inventario
    WHERE Cod_Inventario = @Cod_Inv;

    INSERT INTO #TempNoGPC
    SELECT c.EAN
    FROM Ges_Prd_EstiloColor e with(nolock)
    INNER JOIN Ges_Prd_Productos p with(nolock) ON p.Cod_EstiloColor = e.Cod_EstiloColor
    INNER JOIN Ges_Contadores c  ON c.EAN = p.Codigo_Barra
    WHERE e.Cod_Clasificacion NOT IN (@TipoGpc);

    -- Verificar si hay UPC sin GPC
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempNoGPC)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM #TempNoGPC;
        SET @Status = 3;
        DROP TABLE #TempNoGPC;
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempNoGPC;
    END
END;

/* Inicio la Carga del Conteo 
----------------------------- */
Begin Try
    Begin Transaction 

        Declare @NumRegistros   Integer
        Declare @NumConteos     Integer
        Declare @Cod_Inventario Uniqueidentifier
        Declare @Id_Inventario  Integer
        Declare @Cod_Conteo     Uniqueidentifier
        Declare @Id_Conteo      Int
        Declare @Id_ConteoAnt   Int 
        Declare @Usuario_Conteo Varchar(20)

        Select  @NumRegistros = Count(*),
                @NumConteos = Sum(Total)
        from Ges_Contadores         

        --
        print @NumRegistros 
        Print @NumConteos 

        Select  Top 1
                @Cod_Inventario = Pro.Cod_Inventario ,  
                @Id_Inventario  = Pro.Id_Inventario
        From    Gestion.dbo.Ges_TIM_Inventarios Pro With(NoLock)
        Where   Cod_Tienda = @Cod_Tienda
        And     Estado = 'A'
        Order by Id_Inventario Desc

        Set @Cod_Conteo = NewId()

        Insert Into Gestion.dbo.[Ges_TIM_ConteosCab]  
            (   Cod_Conteo,Cod_Inventario,Id_Inventario,Cod_Tienda,Nombre_Archivo,Ruta,Num_Registros,Num_Conteos,Usuario_Carga,Fecha_Carga,Estado,Usuario_Modificacion,Fecha_Modificacion,Id_ConteoAnt  )
        Values (@Cod_Conteo,@Cod_Inventario,@Id_Inventario,@Cod_Tienda,'EXCEL', 'EXCEL',@NumRegistros,@NumConteos,@Usuario,Getdate(),'A','','19000101 00:00:00',0)

        Set @Id_Conteo = @@identity 
        Set @Id_ConteoAnt = 0 

        INSERT INTO Gestion.[dbo].[Ges_TIM_ConteosDet]
            (    Cod_DetalleConteo  ,Id_Conteo          ,Cod_Conteo     ,Cod_Inventario         ,Id_Inventario      ,Tienda         
                ,Bodega             ,Sector             ,Ubicacion      ,EstColTalla            ,Codigo_Barra       ,Cod_Producto   
                ,Cantidad           ,Id_RegCapturador   ,Cod_Tienda     ,Cod_Bodega             ,Cod_Sector         ,Cod_Ubicacion      
                ,Usuario_Conteo     ,Fecha_Conteo        )
        Select  NewId()             ,@Id_Conteo         ,@Cod_Conteo    ,@Cod_Inventario        ,@Id_Inventario     ,Tie.Codigo_Numerico
                ,Par.Valor          ,'SEC000'           ,'UBI000'       ,Prd.EstiloColorTalla   ,Cont.EAN           ,Prd.Cod_Producto
                ,Cont.Total     ,NEWID()            ,Tie.Cod_Tienda ,Par.Cod_Parametro      ,NEWID()            ,NEWID() 
                ,@Usuario           ,Getdate()          
        From        Ges_Contadores                          Cont   
        Inner Join  Gestion.dbo.Ges_Prd_Productos   Prd With(NoLock) On (Prd.Codigo_Barra =  Cont.EAN)
        Inner Join  Gestion.dbo.Ges_Tiendas         Tie With(NoLock) On Tie.Cod_Tienda  = @Cod_Tienda
        Inner Join  Ges_Parametros                  Par With(NoLock) On Par.Tipo        = 'BO' 
                                                                    and Par.Traduccion  = Iif( Cont.Bodega = 'Principal'  , 'D'  , Upper(Left(Cont.Bodega,1)) )

    Commit Transaction

    
    Set @Status = 1
    Return @Status

End Try
Begin Catch
    If @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    Begin
        Rollback Transaction
        Set @Status = 0
        --set @Error = @@ERROR 
        select @Error As Error
        Return @Status
    End
End Catch
   
End


No hay suficiente información para ayudarte. Necesitas identificar en que parte se está tardando y que es lo que causa que se tarde. No conocemos la estructura de las tablas o índices, ni la cantidad de datos que hay en ellas o que se leen. Lo que sí te puedo asegurar es que todos esos hints NOLOCK no sirven para mejorar el rendimiento y solo causaran datos erróneos.

Para hacer más claro el comentario anterior, necesitas compartir cual es la parte lenta del procedimiento, la estructura de las tablas y sus índices, un número apróximado de filas en las tablas y filas que procesas en cada ejecución. Así como también el plan de ejecución de las instrucciones problematicas.
